# Error with 'inject' angular and jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I have been trying to find the problem but Im not capable, so

**Eco:**

Angular and Angular-mocks @1.4.3

Here my karma config file with correct order?

```
...

files: [
  '../../www/lib/angular/angular.js',
  '../../www/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  '../../www/js/core/app.js',
  '../../www/js/core/**/*.js',
  '../../www/js/feature/**/*.js'
],

...
```

My controller test

```
describe('HomeCtrl', function () {
    beforeEach(function() {
        module('app');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function() {

    }));
})
```

Error

```
/Users/rmas/src/node_modules/angular/angular.js:4386:53
forEach@/Users/rmas/src/node_modules/angular/angular.js:336:24
loadModules@/Users/rmas/src/node_modules/angular/angular.js:4346:12
createInjector@/Users/rmas/src/node_modules/angular/angular.js:4272:22
workFn@/Users/rmas/src/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2393:60
```

So I think the problem is angular-mocks ? I have tried with 1.5 version (angular and angular-mocks).

Module is 'app' is not a typing error.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: At the end I have cleaned all dependencies and reinstalled again, everything is working now with 1.4.3. Thanks for reading me !

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, the issue was that I was not loading all needed modules, I missed the uiBootstrap module from loading and it was causing that issue as it was a dependency in my app.

Please verify if you have all required modules loaded in the Karma Configuration before trying to inject dependencies.